# Symfony Bundles : DoctrineCacheBundle - Memcached

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine, memcached

I'm testing a DoctrineCacheBundle of Symfony on XAMPP. and IDE is  phpstorm.
but I have an issue about PHP Fatal error : Class 'Memcached' not found in ...

 
Can you give me an advice ?

my configuration is below.

# php.ini

```
extension=php_memcache.dll
```

/app/config/config.yml

# Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.cache.memcached
```

# Doctrine Cache

```
doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        service_connection_memcached_provider:
            memcached:
                connection_id: "memcached_connection_service"
```

/app/config/services.yml

```
services:
    memcached_connection_service:
        class: "Memcached"
        calls:
            - [ addServers, [ "%memcached_servers%" ]]

    doctrine.cache.memcached:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache
        calls:
            - [ setMemcached, ['@memcached_connection_service']]
```

# Terminal

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2739

Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2739
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-cache-bundle\Tests\Functional\Fixtures\Memcached.php on line 8

Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-cache-bundle\Tests\Functional\Fixtures\Memcached.php on line 8
```

Comment: The most interesting part about this issue is that somehow `vendor\doctrine\doctrine-cache-bundle\Tests\Functional\Fixtures\Memcached` file is loaded even if no usages of that class is anywhere in the code that's being run. Has the same issue and this was what was really strange.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache and Memcached are different extensions.

You have a Memcache extenstion, but dependencies use better and maintained Memcached.